# error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type C plus plus, How can I solve this issue?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I am trying to access binary files here, I have a file named teacher.dat which is a binary file. How should I fix this issue?

```
fstream fp;
    Teacher obj;
    int found = 0;
    fp.open("teacher.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    while (fp.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj)) && found == 0)
    {
        if (obj.GetEmail() == email)
        {

            obj.display();
            string password;
            cout << "\nEnter The New password : ";
            cin >> password;
            obj.SetPassword(password);
//Error is indicated here
        int pos = (-1)*sizeof(obj);
            fp.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
            fp.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
            found = 1;
        }
        else{
            cout << "\a Invalid email !" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cast `sizeof(obj);` to `int`: `int pos = -1*(int)sizeof(obj);`

Comment: Casting suggested by πάντα ῥεῖ is not safe. Since it's going to be casted to **streamoff** in the seekp method, this is a good candidate for casting:

streamoff pos = -static_cast<streamoff>(sizeof(obj));

Comment: Is there any other possible ways for object with different size?

Comment: Instead of trying to compute a position yourself, you could use `tellg` to remember the position before the read, so you can return there later.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
else
{
     cout << "\a Invalid email !" << endl;
}
```

and write

```
if (!found)
{
     cout << "\a Invalid email !" << endl;
}
```

out of while() loop.

```
int pos = -1 * (signed)sizeof(obj);
```